# Let $f$ be a field with only one singularity in the origin. Show that the phase diagram of the field $f$ has exactly three distinct orbits

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R $ be a field with only one singularity in the origin. Show that the phase diagram of the field $f$ has exactly three distinct orbits which are the following:

[image]

I need help, I tried a lot to solve this question without success

Thanks a lot

Comment: "field with only one singularity in" $\:\mapsto\:$ "vector field whose unique equilibrium is" $\;\;$ ? $\hspace{.8 in}$

Comment: @RickyDemer singularity = equilibrium point?

Comment: I'm guessing that's what you mean by singularity. $\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer a singular point is where $f$ vanishes. Indeed, it is the same thing as an equilibrium point in this context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you misunderstood the problem, because it does not make sense to me as stated. If it said "there are exactly three types of orbit structure", that would make more sense.

Also, it has to be assumed somewhere that $f$ is continuous.

Since $0$ is the only place where $f$ vanishes, we have $f\ne 0$ on $(0,\infty)$. By the intermediate value theorem, one of the following holds (why?)

1. $f>0$ on $(0,\infty)$
2. $f<0$ on $(0,\infty)$

Similarly, one of the following holds

A. $f>0$ on $(-\infty,0)$
 B. $f<0$ on $(-\infty,0)$

Now draw the orbits corresponding the four scenarios 1A, 1B, 2A, 2B: which of these pictures are essentially different, and which two have a lot in common?

Comment: Thank you a lot, I'm very grateful for your answer. Can you see my edit, if I drew the pictures correctly?

Comment: @user42912 I don't understand your added picture. The positive direction of the real number line is usually to the right. So, the arrow should point to the right where $f>0$ and to the left where $f<0$. Pictures 1A and 1B in the right column are correct.

Comment: How can I see this ODE? $x'=f(x)$?

Comment: @user42912 Think in terms of wind in one-dimensional world. The velocity of wind at point $x$ is $f(x)$. This means the wind blows to the right where $f>0$ and to the left where $f<0$.   Differential equation $x'=f(x)$ describes the behavior of a particle floating in air. If it is initially placed at $0$, it remains there. Elsewhere, it will be blown to the left or to the right, according to the sign of $f$. ¶ If this is what you meant by "seeing"...

Comment: yes, thank you very much again, now I understood your point.