# Every solution of $x'= f(x)$ is trivial or regular

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I prove that every solution of $x'= f(x)$, ($x$ is a function from an open interval to $\mathbb R^n$) is trivial or regular?

I need a hint or something to begin to solve this question.

Thanks a lot

**EDIT**

- Note that we have to prove that a solution of an ODE of this form
  hasn't singularities, except in the trivial solution.
- $f$ is a $C^1$ class function.
- Regular in this context means $f(x)\neq 0$ for each $x$.
- Trivial in this context means $f(x)=0$ for each $x$

Comment: @Amzoti the question explains some particular results which arises from this question, anything important I think.

Comment: @julianfernandez yes, or course, I'm sorry I will edit the question.

Comment: @julianfernandez is it ok now?

Comment: do you mean $f : I \to \mathbb{R} , I \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ ?

Comment: @DanZimm I meant $f:I\to \mathbb R^n$, $I\subset \mathbb R$

Comment: "Every solution of $x = f(x)$ [is]  _______, or it's trivial or regular." Or do you mean "every solution....IS [either] trivial or regular"?

Comment: @amWhy thank you for your remark, I've already edited the question

Comment: Thanks, but you might want to omit "[or it's]", and state simply "...is trivial or regular."

Comment: also you still say "$x$ is a function from an open interval" - if you meant $f$ i would change that and specify the exact domain and codomian

Comment: @amWhy Thank you for your suggestion, I've already edited again.

Comment: I still don't understand. Are there any assumptions about $f$, is it continuous, for example?  Is the equation $x'=f(x)$ (prime is missing from the question)? I guess that "trivial" means a constant solution? but that would be "regular" for me.  I don't know what "regular" means here. "Regular" is an overloaded word in mathematics, its meaning is impossible to tell without context.

Comment: @75064 is it ok now?

Comment: $x=f(x)$ is not a differential equation. Perhaps you wanted to write something else.

Comment: @MartinSleziak thank you for the remark, I've realized of that mistake just before you mentioned it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for fixing the question. The starting point is the [Picard uniqueness theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem). It applies here because a $C^1$ satisfies the Lipschitz condition on every closed interval.

The uniqueness of solution means:

> If two solutions agree at some moment, they agree at all times.

Let's rephrase this in the special case when the second solution is a trivial one.

> If a  solution  is at a singular point at some moment, it is there at all times.

Which is what you were asked to show.

Comment: but there is a problem, I think you have to use the fact of homogeneity of $f$, because there is some ODE's which are singular in some points and regular in another points.

Comment: @user42912 Those other ODEs, such as $x'=x^{1/3}$, have a function $f$ that does not satisfy the Lipschitz condition. As I said, the assumption  $f\in C^1$ guarantees the Lipschitz condition holds.

Comment: do you know where can I see the phase diagram of this function?

Comment: @user42912 It's the second diagram in your question http://math.stackexchange.com/q/387063/75064   but you don't see the difference between uniqueness and non-uniqueness from the phase diagram.

Comment: do you mean that if f is locally Lipschitz, then its phase diagram can't be like this http://postimg.org/image/zfybl1w89/ with a singularity in the origin?

Comment: @user42912 Not at all. There is no obvious relation between phase diagram and the Lipschitz condition. The phase diagram shows some aspects of the equation, and does not show others.

Comment: But if the other solutions aren't the trivial ones?